# Making a simple item list contain 2 variables per item

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make an android-app that shows a list of albums and it displays the album-title on each listitem. So far so good. 
But I would also need the album-id somehow connected to each listitem to use when I get the next level to list (the album-tracks). How can I in each list item store more values for the items then the displayed text (album-title)?

Right now Im using an ArrayList (to store the album-titles) that is connected to a ArrayAdapter wich use the simple_list_item_1 layout. I get the album-info (title, artist, id) form external xml.

I was thinking on using a multidimensional array but I don't know how to connect it to the ArrayAdapter since it only is expecting an array?

Any suggestions on how I should tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple list adapter you should use android custom list view.
Check out this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dynamic-listview-%E2%80%93part3)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try Android sample demo project

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't find the solution for my problem though. I see there are several listtypes to use but I can not see how to assign mutliple values to each list-item in the examples. Some use the position of the clicked item to print out wich item is clicked. To illustrate my problem more would be to make an link list. Each listitem would need to contain the link text and the URL. The link text is displayed on the list-item but how do you assosiate/connect/attach an URL to that individual list-item?